# mysql container stops after executing command in commands parameter

Tags: docker-compose

the mysql container stops after executing the command in the command parameter. Moreover, if you run it without the command parameter, the container runs and does not stop. Terminates with exit 0. The logs are empty.

```
mysql:
  image: mysql:8.0
  # build: docker/db/
  volumes:
    - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    - ./docker/db/dump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dump.sql
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: auto
    MYSQL_DATABASE: auto
    MYSQL_USER: modx
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: modx123
  command: ["sh", "-c", "cd /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ && ls"]
```

Я пробовал использовать tail -f dev/null для того чтобы контейнер не закрывался. Но это нерабочий способ

Comment: According to SO questions has to be write in english